# What does a [] square bracket mean in pointer class in C++?

Tags: c++, pointers

```
class Box
{
public:
    // Constructor definition
    Box(double l = 2.0, double b = 2.0, double h = 2.0)
    {
        cout << "Constructor called." << endl;
        length = l;
        breadth = b;
        height = h;
    }
    double Volume()
    {
        return length * breadth * height;
    }
private:
    double length;     // Length of a box
    double breadth;    // Breadth of a box
    double height;     // Height of a box
};

int main(void)
{
    Box Box1(3.3, 1.2, 1.5);    // Declare box1
    Box Box2(8.5, 6.0, 2.0);    // Declare box2
    Box *ptrBox;                // Declare pointer to a class.

                                // Save the address of first object
    ptrBox = &Box1;

    ptrBox[0]; // <--- What does it do?

}
```

Comment: `double Volume()` should probably be `double Volume() const` since it doesn't change `*this`.

Answer (score 1):

```
ptrBox[0]
```

Is equivalent to:

```
*ptrBox
```

Pointers support the same indexing operator that arrays do. Aside from the associated storage, an array variable is just a pointer to the first element of an array, so it makes sense that pointers and arrays can be indexed in a semantically identical way.

Comment: Arrays are not pointers. They decay to pointers. And they don't actually have an indexing operator : the `[]` just decays the array, then indexes the resulting pointer.

Comment: @Quentin Thanks for clearing that up. You can either add your own answer, propose an edit to mine, or I will incorporate your text into my answer (with credit).